Not able to get all containers in one column
I want create a table visualization in grafana to get CPU, Memory, Disk, Network details.
Container   CPU Usage (%)   Memory Usage (Bytes)    Disk Reads (Bytes)  Network In (Bytes)
cadvisor          15.5                 1.2 GB                  10 MB            200 KB/s
nginx-container   20.3                 800 MB                  15 MB            500 KB/s

I want table in this format but it is creating different columns for different containers.
label_replace(rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{name=~"$container"}[$__range]), "resource", "cpu", "", "")
or
#Current memory usage in GB
label_replace(
    container_memory_usage_bytes{name=~"$container"} / (1024 * 1024 * 1024), "resource", "memory", "", "")
or
label_replace(
    container_fs_usage_bytes{name=~"$container"} / (1024 * 1024 * 1024), "resource", "disk", "", "")
or
label_replace(
  (
    rate(container_network_receive_bytes_total{name=~"$container"}[$__range]) * (1024 / 1024 / 1024)
    + rate(container_network_transmit_bytes_total{name=~"$container"}[$__range]) * (1024 / 1024 / 1024)
  ), "resource", "network", "", ""
)

I have used this query and Join by field, Labels to fields and Rename fields by regex transformation in my case.

We might need a little more information, but I think we have enough to get started. From your query, I’m assuming you’re using a prometheus data source, and that you’ve got 4 metric series that you’re trying query and union together with ORs. Rather, than ORing metrics into another time series, I might recommend approaching this with 4 different queries and then using Grafana Transformations to combine and organize the results.

More specifically, In your grafana panel settings, create 4 seperate queries and then make sure that the query format and type for each are set to Table and Instant respectively. This will put the data in a format that Table visualizations can use. Next, we’re going to take apart your query. I would copy the parts inside of each of the label_replace methods into each query, i.e. rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{name=~"$container"}[$__range]).

This will create 4 distinct time series that we now need to merge together, which we can do with a Join by Field tranformation on the name field. This will create a super table with each of the columns from each of the metrics though, so we want to reduce those down to just the ones that we want. Use an Organize Fields by Name transformation to hide all the fields that you don’t care about except name and Values A, B, C, and D, and then rename A, B, C, and D to CPU, Memory, Disk, and Network.

Without being able to see all your panel setting and the details of your metrics, it might take some back and forth to understand the problem and solution, but these steps out and let us know how they go so that we can get to a solution.
